# How to say something is [a colour] AND [another adjective] using て form 'and'?

Tags: て-form, i-adjectives, na-adjectives, colors

Do all colours work as な adjectives **or** い adjectives when using て form 'and'? In a sentence such as "my phone is white and small", would it be 私のけいたいは白い**で**小さいです。OR ～けいたいはしろ**くて**～? 
Also, if the colour were to change to a less basic colour, like はいいろ, would the 'and' form change?

Answer (score 3):

Japanese colors are [nouns that work as **no**-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010), except for [six basic colors](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36048/5010) which also have i-adjective versions. I don't think there is a color name that works as a **na**-adjective.

- 白くて is correct but 白いで is ungrammatical, because 白い is an i-adjective. 白で is acceptable, but 白くて is much more common. Similarly, you should usually say 赤くて小さい, 青くて小さい, 黒くて小さい, and so on, while 赤で/青で/黒で is also sometimes used.
- 灰色で is correct but 灰色くて is ungrammatical, because 灰色 is a **no**-adjective. Similarly, you should say 緑色で小さい, オレンジで小さい, ピンクで小さい, and so on.