# What's the difference between あか and あかい

Tags: grammar

I see both used for the color red.  Can someone tell me what the difference is.

Comment: We have a question just like yours already. If the answer on the linked question is not satisfactory, please edit your question to be more specific (preferably with examples) and it might be reopened.

Comment: What do you mean "on the linked"?  Thanks

Comment: The linked question http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33998/using-i-adjective-color-words